# Excel SQL Query - Multiple Parameters

Tags: sql, excel

I'm using excel 15.32 on Mac and am doing a database connection to my company's MySQL database. It is the "database" option and not the "SQL server ODBC".

My query looks something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(requisition_item.qty)


FROM requisition_item
INNER JOIN requisition
ON requisition.id = requisition_item.requisitionId

WHERE requisition_item.itemId IN (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) AND requisition.requiredBy >= '2016-08-01'
```

And in parameters I map EACH "?" to a specific cell. Is there a way to make that cleaner? Can I map to a range for a count function? It's a pain to map each one especially as my list grows!

EDIT: I am counting how many times a group of numbers (located in ColA of an Excel spreadsheet) appears in my requisition_items table. I map each "?" (Excel names them Parameter1, Parameter2, etc.) to each ColA cell (A1, A2, etc.) The query simply outputs a count of how many times each value that I type in ColA appears in that table.

Comment: I don't understand what you are actually doing.  Are you talking about adding every cell of the itemId column? Can you give a small sample of your dataset?

Comment: Does the list consist of values which are somewhere in the database? In that case checking against a subquery would be more maintainable.

Comment: Thanks. See edit

Comment: you're probably better off generating that query programmatically, rather than keep adding to it manually every time you add a parameter?